# Using "already" in the future scheduled time

Tags: tense

Is it okay to use "already" in the future scheduled time meaning that the decision has already been made and, thus, the time is occupied?

For example, can I say

> "Jenny invited me to go swimming with her this Wednesday, but I am
>   **already** doing one sport this Wednesday, so I can't go with her"

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

You can think about it as "I already made plans to do a different sport" if that helps you think about it better.